# Unable to page-break as desired with css

Tags: html, css, printing, page-break

I am trying to create a style sheet for what I believe to be rather simple html structure, yet I am unable to achieve what I want.

The structure of the html is as follows:

It conssists of *chapters* (class: `.chapter`).

Each chapter has and starts with a *title* (class: `.chapter-title`).

A chapter consists of *items* (class: `.item`).

An item consists of *paragraphs* (class: `.paragraph`).

When the document is printed, I want no page break between `.chapter-title` and the *first* `.item`, and I want no page break within an `.item`. Page breaks between `.item`s are ok.

This is what I have tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><!--{-->

  <title>Chapter, items and paragraphs</title>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

   <!--{--><style type='text/css'>

     body {
       font-family:Garamond;
     }

     .chapter {
        page-break-inside:avoid;
     }

     .chapter-title + .item {
        page-break-before:avoid;
     }

     .chapter-title {
        font-size: 30px;
        page-break-after:avoid;
     }

     .item {
        border: 1px dashed #ccc;
        page-break-inside:avoid;
     }

     .paragraph {
        height:5cm;
        border: 1px solid #7cf;
        margin:0.1cm;
     }

   </style><!--}-->

</head><!--}-->
<body><!--{-->

<div class='chapter'>
      <div class='chapter-title'>Chapter 1</div>

      <div class='item'>
        <div class='paragraph'>1 / 1 / Para 1</div>
      </div>

      <div class='item'>
        <div class='paragraph'>1 / 2 / Para 1</div>
        <div class='paragraph'>1 / 2 / Para 2</div>
      </div>

</div>

<div class='chapter'>
      <div class='chapter-title'>Chapter 2</div>

      <div class='item'>
        <div class='paragraph'>2 / 1 / Para 1</div>
        <div class='paragraph'>2 / 1 / Para 2</div>
      </div>

      <div class='item'>
        <div class='paragraph'>2 / 2 / Para 1</div>
      </div>

</div>

<div class='chapter'>
      <div class='chapter-title'>Chapter 3</div>

      <div class='item'>
        <div class='paragraph'>3 / 1 / Para 1</div>
        <div class='paragraph'>3 / 1 / Para 2</div>
      </div>

      <div class='item'>
        <div class='paragraph'>3 / 2 / Para 1</div>
      </div>

      <div class='item'>
        <div class='paragraph'>3 / 3 / Para 1</div>
        <div class='paragraph'>3 / 3 / Para 2</div>
        <div class='paragraph'>3 / 3 / Para 3</div>
      </div>

      <div class='item'>
        <div class='paragraph'>3 / 4 / Para 1</div>
        <div class='paragraph'>3 / 4 / Para 2</div>
      </div>

</div>


</body><!--}-->
</html>
```

If printed (chrome, page size A4) I have a page break between **Chapter 3** and its first *element*. I tried some variations of the above but this is the closest to what I need. So, is there a style sheet to accomplish what I want?

Please note that the css `height` attribute for `.paragraph` is only here to artificially "blow up" the size of the document. In the "real" document, there is more text, making the .paragraphs of varying heights.

**Edit** wrong *elements* renamed to *items*.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `:first-child` to your css here is a great site for css, it's helped me a lot in the past.

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-child/

Comment: I am not sure how your suggestion helps my case.